# Redirect custom URLs via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my own domain:

> http://cesarferreira.com

and I wanna make

> http://cesarferreira.com/github

point to

> https://github.com/cesarferreira

Without having to make a /github/ folder with an index.html with a redirect for each page I own (facebook, twitter, pinterest, etc)

Is there a way like for example htaccess catchig *.com/github and pointing to a given static url?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your document root serves -

```
http://cesarferreira.com
```

you can put a redirect in `.htaccess` like -

```
Redirect /github https://github.com/cesarferreira
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at URL rewriter 'http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html'. That should be able to do everything you want and more.
As long as it is enabled in apache then you can use it in .htaccess files also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /github https://github.com/cesarferreira
```

Or if you only want github to point only to the folder:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/github https://github.com/cesarferreira
```

You can put that in the htaccess file of your document root.